# Can I warp and keep lines smooth?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform

I have applied a warp to an image I am making and it has made the lines look very jagged.

[image]

Is there any trick I can do to make these lines look smooth?

Comment: Those are not lines. Those are pixels - and you cannot warp "a" pixel.

Comment: It is a smart object so photoshop has the data about vector paths.  Reading between the lines of your response I am assuming warp first rasterizes before altering?  I wondered is there any way to anti-alias these lines as the jaggedness looks really bad.  I could draw over it with the pen tool I guess but I wondered if there was a better way as part of the warp process or some post process maybe.  In my files im working at fairly high resolution and these edges still appear so there are plenty of pixels available to mitigate effect but it still appears bad.

Comment: Well photosop does rasterize it...  @Guerrilla try doing the same in illustrator

Comment: OK cool, I'll re-do it in illustrator.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to do this is in Illustrator rather than Photoshop. Photoshop is a pixel-based application, which means that each edge of each shape has to be made of pixels, which can look jagged when moved around, as you experienced. Taking the same image and working with it in Illustrator. However, the next problem that you'll run into is that the image you are using is a pixel-image, not a vector. Illustrator solves this by letting you live trace the image, and then expand the appearance to be able to warp the image. But it is going to take some finagling on your part to get it to work.
Good luck!